# Bind same data to all elements and append from datum

Tags: d3.js

I have many elements created from a data set `data`. I would then like to bind `same_data` to every element, and depict the same svg elements on every element.

I am using `datum` to bind `same_data` to every element, but I'm not sure how to append elements based on `same_data`. If `same_data` is 72 instances long, how do I append 72 circles to each of my original elements?

Am I working in the wrong direction?

```
var element = svg.selectAll('.element')
    .data(data);

var element_enter = element.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class','element');

element_enter.append('g')
    .datum(same_data)
    // append('circle') ??
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to nest the data and then use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I thought you were referring to directly nesting the data such as with `d3.nest` but your link and the linked [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111) demonstrates nested selections clearly. The fix was as easy as the following: `d3.selectAll('.element').selectAll('.circle').data(same_data).enter().append('circle').attr('class','circle')`

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way as well. What I mean by nesting is making `same_data` members of the top-level `data`, e.g. `data[0].nested = same_data`. This will make the dependencies more explicit.

Comment: Definitely, I wanted to avoid this explicit nesting because `data` and `same_data` are coming from different sources, frequently – so as to stay true to the original representation. But both of these alternatives are extremely good solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111) and this [guide](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) as reference:

```
var element = svg.selectAll('.element')
    .data(data);

var element_enter = element.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class','element');

element.selectAll('.circle')
    .data(same_data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'circle')
```

Use chained `selectAll()` i.e. `element.selectAll('.circle')`.